# Cleaner way to access custom fields in code?

Tags: functions

I have 15 custom fields that I use to generate reviews for my site. Currently I access each field like this:

```
//Buy or rent, type home, price
                 if ( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'survey_home_type', true) ) {
                    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'survey_home_type', true) . " - ";
                 } 
                 if ( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'survey_buy_or_rent', true) ) {
                    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'survey_buy_or_rent', true) . " for ";
                 }
                 if ( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'survey_purchase_price', true) ) {
                    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'survey_purchase_price', true);
                 } elseif ( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'survey_rent', true) ) {
                    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'survey_rent', true);
                 }
```

Is there a better way to do this? I tried using get_post_custom but it seems to mainly deal with arrays, not single items. I could also declare all the variables ahead of time, such as `$rent`, `$purchase_price`. I would like to hear any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a function to handle the monotony of this task.

```
function my_print_meta($id, $key, $alternate = '')
{
    if($value = get_post_meta($id, $key, true))
        echo $value;
    else
        echo $alternate;
}
```

Notice in the function that I only call `get_post_meta` once and store the value in a variable so that two separate database queries don't need to be made. With this function set, I would then call it in a template file using:

```
my_print_meta(get_the_ID(), 'survey_home_type', 'No Home Type');
```

Now, realize that this function, with the way that it manages the "alternate" text might not work for your template, but this is just an idea to get you going

Comment: I agree with wrapper function approach but I'd change condition to `false !== $value`. A lot of things loosely evaluate to false - empty strings, empty arrays. Storing such in option is technically different from option having nothing stored in it.

Comment: @tollmanz - thank you, I like this a lot. Good idea on creating a default type.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [get_post_custom()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom)

It's not a lot different, but a little less code.

```
$meta = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
if( $meta ) 
{ 
    echo $meta['survey_home_type'];
    echo $meta['survey_buy_or_rent'];
    echo $meta['survey_rent'];
}
```

Comment: I've not used get_post_custom before as I prefer to query the meta data separately. Did you forget to change the keys in the conditional statements or is there a reason that you are always checking for 'survey_home_type'? I do like that you are only making one query here.

Comment: @tollmanz `get_post_custom()` is the "native" function _behind_ `get_post_meta()` and returns an array of all attached meta data. The only thing that _could_ be changed is the `if` statement. Not necessary to call that for every line, but i guess the above is for demonstrational purpose only.

Comment: @tollmanz - Yes, I did forget to change the keys in the IF statement.

Comment: @kaiser - thanks for the clarification. I'm not sure why I've missed this function before.

Comment: Actually, the generic function behind get_post_meta() is now get_metadata(). Whichever you use, you never do more than one query per post, as the metadata is cached.

Comment: @kaiser - I tried this out but each variable is an array. So I still need to call "true" at the end of the function to get the first instance of that meta. I will give that a shot though... this does look a lot cleaner!

Comment: To answer you caseym since this came up a Google search, you need to do `echo $meta['survey_home_type'][0];` for example to grab the first value in Pippins answer above.